# How many tabs can be restored in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

We can restore closed tabs(previous session tabs) by ctrl + shift + T. Is there any limitation to the number of tabs we can reopen?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limitation.You can reopen **all** the tabs that you have closed.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers

Answer (score -1):

No there is no limit, i once restored approx 35 tabs after crash

Comment: Did you restore a window of 35 tabs? Or You restored it one tab at a time?

Comment: I had approx 35 tabs opened in my chrome window, when chrome crashed i again opened the chrome and after click on restore tabs, all the tabs are restored